# Capture open user controls in Windows form application

Tags: c#, winforms

How to capture a  open user control in C# windows form application in the run time.I need to capture the user control and dispose it.

Comment: What do you meant by *capture the user control*?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming by "open user control"  you mean a form, I would go with

```
        foreach (Form form in Application.OpenForms)
        {
            if (form.Text == "xyz")//your form
            {
                //...
            }

        }
```